# What caching headers does JQueryMobile respect?

Tags: jquery-mobile, http-caching, jquery-mobile-ajax

I have the following headers set coming down for a mobile page written in C# (ASP.Net) that I have which uses JQueryMobile.  However, when using the back/forward buttons in  my browser the page does not get re-downloaded (confirmed with Fiddler that the page is downloaded once and even though it's expired based on the headers set it still uses a cached copy of the page).  Here are the headers:

Cache-Control: public, max-age=10
Expires: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 05:55:57 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 05:55:47 GMT

I'm setting these on the ASP.Net pages by using the OutputCache directive
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="None" %>

Are there other headers I can set on the page that JQueryMobile and/or my browser will respect?  In general I'm finding a lot of user experience problems with JQueryMobile and having JavaScript on the page for various button actions.  I have read a good amount of the documentation about JQueryMobile AJAX and the JQueryMobile navigation model but I can't seem to find general guidance on forcing a page to "expire" or force it to re-download with headers which seems to me to be the simplest way.  I'm not sure if it's browsers being overly aggressive in caching or the JQueryMobile code doing this.

Comment: I saw this other post and will try it though it's pretty old:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932678/stop-jquery-mobile-from-caching-dynamic-page

Comment: Still am unable to get this to work correctly.  Watching with fiddler and trying to even specify no caching does not force the page to re-downloaded and I'm left with a valid page but my javascript methods seem to be nonexistent.